# How to choose address in BlockChain Android Application?

Tags: blockchain.info, android

If I want to receive funds using the Blockchain Android application I click on the arrow on the top of the screen which brings up the Request Bitcoin screen, showing the QR-code for easy scanning.

The problem is that the QR-code is for the original address generated when I first created my Blockchain wallet.  Even though I have created additional addresses I don't see any way to change the receiving address with the Android application.

Is the option to specify a different receiving address not an option on the Blockchain Android application or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are missing something :)

Go to the address book and, by long tapping, choose "set as default address".
That address will be the one that generate the qr code.